# Parsing nested arrays and objects with Aeson

Tags: haskell, aeson

I am having problems writing a `FromJSON` instance to parse a JSON file containing an array of objects nested within another array of objects. The file is of the form:

```
[{"family":[{"name":"Jane","age":31,}
           ,{"name":"Ana","age":15,}]}
,{"family":[{"name":"Julia","age":45}
           ,{"name":"Chris","age":47}]}]
```

For that I created two new types:

```
-- A person
data Person = Person { name :: String
                     , age  :: Int} deriving (Show, Eq)

-- A family is a list of list of Person
newtype Family = Family {unFamily :: [[Person]]} deriving (Show, Eq)
```

And their instances are these (using `XOverloadedStrings`, `aeson` and `text`):

```
instance ToJSON Person where
  toJSON (Person n a) = object [ "name" .= n
                               , "age"  .= a]
instance FromJSON Person where
  parseJSON (Object o) = Person
    <$> o .:? "name" .!= ""
    <*> o .:? "age"  .!= 0
  parseJSON _ = mzero

instance ToJSON Family where
  toJSON (Family c) = toJSON . map (\v -> object $ ("family",v):[]) 
                             $ map toJSON c
```

I can make some tests like (with `bytestring` and `maybe` loaded)

```
> julia = Person "Julia" 45
> (== julia) . fromMaybe (Person "" 0) . decode . encode $ julia
True
> BS.putStrLn . BL.toStrict . encode $ Family [[julia,julia],[julia]]
[{"family":[{"age":45,"name":"Julia"},{"age":45,"name":"Julia"}]},{"family":[{"age":45,"name":"Julia"}]}]
```

and everything works as I wanted. But as I said, I couldn't write `FromJSON Family`, so I can't test like `decode . encode` as I did to `julia`.

I looked at the many types involved in `aeson` trying to find a way to make it work, but I simply couldn't do it. I could at least write `toJSON` for `ToJSON Family` because I learned that `type Pair = (Text, Value)`.

Can anyone point me in a direction here? And is there a better way to write   `ToJSON Family`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would write

```
newtype Family = Family {unFamily :: [Person]}
```

instead. Then

```
instance FromJSON Family where
    parseJSON (Object o) = Family <$> (o .: "family")
    parseJSON v = typeMismatch "family" v
instance ToJSON Family where
    toJSON (Family c) = "family" .= c
```

should do the trick for the instances, and the `FromJSON`/`ToJSON` instances you get for free for `[Family]` will decode the example JSON you showed us/encode the example family you showed us as you want.

Answer (score 1):

You can make a function that parses a sublist, and then use `mapM` to convert the sublists:

```
import Data.Foldable(toList)

instance FromJSON Family where
    parseJSON (Array arr) = Family <$> mapM parseSubList (toList arr)
        where parseSubList (Object o) = o .:? "family" .!= []
```

For example:

```
Prelude Data.Aeson Data.Foldable> decode "[{\"family\":[{\"age\":45,\"name\":\"Julia\"},{\"age\":45,\"name\":\"Julia\"}]},{\"family\":[{\"age\":45,\"name\":\"Julia\"}]}]" :: Maybe Family
Just (Family {unFamily = [[Person {name = "Julia", age = 45},Person {name = "Julia", age = 45}],[Person {name = "Julia", age = 45}]]})
```

Comment: After understanding the types used in `aeson`, I tried doing it something like this, but I used regular `map` and `Vector.toList`. It didn't work. In the end, monads were the answer.